# how to run and check run in python

Tags: python, regex

I am completely new in Python.I need to write a python script which parse the request url of apache and find some data out of it.

Script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    ipAddress = re.search('ipAddress=([^&]*)', line)
    key = re.search('key=([^&]*)', line)
    if len(ipAddress.group(1)) != 0 and len(key.group(1)) != 0:
        print "%s\t%s" % (ipAddress.group(1), key.group(1))
```

Please tell me what is the error in the script and how to test it with input like this:

```
GET request?key=xxxxxxxxxx&ipAddress=000.000.000.00&id=blah... HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Or even just executing some code in the Python console to see what happens?

Comment: You need to provide more information here. I executed that script, pasted in your example, and got the output. Obviously the code as posted works, but perhaps not as expected. Can you tell us what you're seeing, and what you expected?

Comment: Whats the problem of using the urlparse module.

Comment: Check `urlparse` in the standard library, which will help you to parse such strings correctly and safely.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what error you're getting, and your code doesn't generate any error for me, but I can see a few things that could go bad with your code.

First, you just want the URL, not the method and HTTP version (which could cause some problems if ipAddress or key were the last fields), so you should split the line before parsing it:

```
method, url, version = line.split(' ')
```

Second, you *will* get errors if the url doesn't contain either a `key` or `ipAddress` field, because your match checking code is faulty. You should use this code instead:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    method, url, version = line.split(' ')
    ipAddress = re.search('ipAddress=([^&]*)', url)
    key = re.search('key=([^&]*)', url)
    if ipAddress and key:
        print "%s\t%s" % (ipAddress.group(1), key.group(1))
```